# springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, sql-server-2008, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

We have an issue while reading from or writing to Microsoft SQL DB using spring framework:

Exception connecting to db
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.".

We can't say that it's about 1% of all connections as stated in MS article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/11/30/intermittent-jdbc-connectivity-issue-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption-error-sql-server-returned-an-incomplete-respons/

It's much more often.

This issue causing data loss from the DB so it's very important for us to find the way to fix it.

We have:

MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) 10.50.6000.34 (X64)

Java 6 Update 35

ODBC Driver SQL Server 6.01.7601.17514

spring-jdbc-2.5.6.jar

sqljdbc4-2.0.1803.100.jar

We can't disable cypher like stated in article above and can't move to JAVA 8.

Has anybody faced the same issue already?